# How do you represent $\Im$ and $\Re$ on paper?

Tags: soft-question, complex-numbers, notation

Do you draw $\Im$ and $\Re$ just like they are or you write $\mathtt {Im}$ and $\mathtt{Re}$?

Comment: Im or Re, but Im is also used for the image of an application. Usually, it's not a problem.

Comment: I based my life path on the knowing that doing set theory will render this sort of question moot. (And also because I really liked set theory since my first meeting with it... :-P)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I doubt set theory has absolutely no ambiguous or variable (between different countries, typically) notation. I know at least one counterexample: how do you write the power set? I have seen $\mathcal{P}(A)$, $\mathfrak{B}(A)$, but I personnaly prefer $2^A$ (of polish origin, by the way, IIRW)

Comment: @Jean: $\mathcal P$, of course. And that's not even the least of your problems, when you have $\Bbb P$ as a forcing, and you write something like $\exists p\in\Bbb P: p\Vdash_\Bbb P|\mathcal P(\omega_1)|=\mathfrak p$. Sometimes $P$ enters the formula as well. But my handwriting is excellent, when I'm bored or stuck I work my calligraphy. Especially these strange fonts. :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to my nearly unreadable handwriting, I prefer Im and Re instead of the calligraphic symbols, as noone would be able to read them. I've never seen anyone use the calligraphic symbols in real life either.

Answer (score 2):

I personally write Re and Im on my preprints, too. It seems to me that Re $z$ is much more elegant than $\Re z$.

Comment: Do you at least have it declared as a math operator, or something?

Comment: Yes, of course. In LaTeX I define `\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re}`

Comment: Phew. Now I can `\relax` :-P